# Different sizes of data in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have this sample chart that I made in MS Excel. Each data are different in sizes based on the legend above. Is this possible in Chart.js?

[image]

Comment: Of course, yes! Stacked bar chart https://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/NrROeB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I researched and it turns out it's possible by using null values!